# Concatenating Thousands of Text Files Across Hundreds of Directories (while keeping some structure)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a set of plain text files spread across 400+ directories, with tons and tons of subdirectories. There are about 300,000 text files. For example:

```
directory1/subdirectory1
directory1/subdirectory2
directory1/subdirectory1/subdirectory3
```

All of those text files within `directory1` should end up in one big massive text file named `directory1.txt`. Then repeat with `directory2`.

What would be the quickest and simplest way to go into each of these four hundred directories and combine all of the text files in such a manner?

I know I could go to each of the four hundred directories and use the commands such as `find` to bring all the text files together into one directory, and then use `cat *.txt >> all.txt`, but surely there must be an easy way to automate this process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To concatenate all txt-files in a subtree:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Usage: cat-txt dirname
find "$1" -name \*.txt -print0 | xargs -0 cat >> "$1.txt"
```

Call `cat-txt` on all immediate subdirectories:

```
$ find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec cat-txt '{}' \;
```

Comment: or `find "$1" -name \*.txt -exec cat {} + >> "$1.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

> there must be an easy way to automate this process?

Why are you looking for one? Is this a one time activity or you're gonna repeat it every now and then?

I would just say go with something as simple as:

```
for ff in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d`
do
    find "$ff" -type *.txt -exec cat {} \; >> "$ff.txt"
done
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. Ideally, I would like a solution that I can repeat for further datasets - but this is pretty simple!

Comment: Whatever sails your boat. :). Do test, I'm not connected to any unix boxes right now. I fear something might be wrong with `-exec cat {} \; >> $outFile`, though it looks ok to me right now.

Comment: `help for` doesn't show `for each` syntax. `find . -type d -prune` prints only `.`. You could use [`-mindepth`, `-maxdepth`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144022/concatenating-thousands-of-text-files-across-hundreds-of-directories-while-keep/8144869#8144869). Even if `find ...prune` would print directories it breaks on directories with spaces (or other characters from `IFS`). `{}` might need to be escaped.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks. Updated. `{}` doesn't need quoting/escaping on command line bash.

Comment: It doesn't solve "spaces in a name" issue and `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d` includes `.` in the output.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this on my system, and it works flawlessly. You may want to tweak it to your parameters, but in one line I did everything you needed.

```
for I in `ls -dR */`; do cat $I/* > $I.txt; done
```

You may to change the ls command to only search text files, otherwise you'll get binary data as well. Enjoy.

```
for I in `ls -dR */*.txt`; do cat $I/* > $I.txt; done
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks really promising but it's not quite working for me - I get a string of error messages such as: `cat: ABbenevolat//05-02-11: Is a directory
cat: ABbenevolat//05-04-26: Is a directory
cat: ABpresse//FrancoSection: Is a directory` -- the files themselves aren't being catted, just creating extra .txt ones. I might be messing something obvious here, I'm just learning bash..

Comment: It won't list files in nested directories. It breaks if there is a space in a filename or directory.